# Как изменить стиль forms.IntegerField в Django

Tags: css, python, django, шаблоны, forms

Появилась проблема. А конкретно, при выводе формы в шаблон, поле IntegerField, имеет стандартную джанговскую отрисовку, соответственно теряется адаптивность при работе с мобильной версией проекта. Вопрос в следующем, как переопределить стиль/класс данной формы?
Код формы

Comment: Что значит "стандартную джанговскую отрисовку"?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/GPFUkCL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не "стандартная джанговская отрисовка", а [поле ввода типа number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number). Виджет можно изменить так:

```
some_field = forms.IntegerField(label='Some field', widget=forms.TextInput())
```

Comment: Это пробовал, но не понял, как заставить TextInput() принимать значение в int? coerce как аргумент не принимает.

Comment: В смысле? Виджетам вообще до фонаря на тип данных, они отвечают только за то, в какой html-код отрендериться поле формы. А поле типа `IntegerField` принятые данные преобразует в число.

Comment: Странно, с NumberInput, значения количества обновляются, а с TextInput() значения так и остаются единицей.

Comment: Нужно прогнать под отладчиком, посмотреть что приходит в форму, как преобразуется и как сохраняется в БД.

Comment: `quantity = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, initial=1, label="Количество",
                                  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'special', 'type': 'number'}))`
Получилось вот так, очень странно, что NumberInput, не принимает атрибуты в качестве аргумента, пришлось костылить TextInput, и насильно указывать ему `type=number`. 
Большое спасибо за ответ? Помогли разобраться.